# Spray bottle keeps spraying even when not squeezing trigger

Tags: equipment

I know that spray bottles are usually cheap and konk out or break or whatever much sooner than we would like them to. Yeah that is a bummer, I know. But, I have the opposite problem. I have a sprayer I have used for a long time, refilled and kept using just fine. This last time I refilled the bottle, when I screwed the nozzle back on it started a steady stream continuously that wouldn't stop - I wasn't even pulling the trigger! The only way I can keep it from spraying is to turn the spray nozzle all the way off. I have searched all over the internet and every time I search specifically for "Keeps spraying" "won't stop spraying" "sprays on it's own" every single result has automatically changed it to "won't spray" or "Stops spraying" - I know that happens most of the time, but Jeeza-makreeza I can not be the only person to encounter this. I am pretty sure there is nothing paranormal going on, just something, probably small, that I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please explain how this question is related to cooking? The scope of this site is described in the [help] and it would be good if you could [edit] your post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to cooking.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure inside is greater than pressure outside.
Release the pressure, ensure the temperature is stable. If it's warming, then pressure will increase.

If it builds again after that, then the bottle contents are producing gas, which is not usually a good sign in food.